# App crashes when clicked on back button on a nav controller while function is executing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

On a slow connection when I click on back button on a VC it crashes while accessing navigation controller. VC is already deallocated but setNavBarTitle is executed after going back to another view. I understand that function is executing while VC is already deallocated but Im not sure what's the best way to handle such scenario?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    fetchProfile(clientId: clientId) { (result, error) in
        if result?.data != nil { 
                if (result?.success)! {
                    self.clientProfile = result!.data!
                    // Avatar
                    let clientImageView = UIImageView()

                    if let url = URL(string: result!.data!.pic_url!) {
                        clientImageView.image = UIImage(named: "System/defaultAvatar")
                        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

                            // WARNING: UIImageView.image must be used from main thread only                                
                            clientImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                            self.setNavBarTitle(image: clientImageView.image!)
                        }
                        task.resume()
                    } 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

private func setNavBarTitle(image: UIImage) {
    // Crashes here -> Thread 11: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
}
```

Comment: Never perform UI changes from a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `[weak self]` in your method callback, so even though the method is called after the VC deallocated it wont cause a crash, since self wont be existing:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    fetchProfile(clientId: clientId) { [weak self] (result, error) in
        if result?.data != nil { 
                if (result?.success)! {
                    self?.clientProfile = result!.data!
                    // Avatar
                    let clientImageView = UIImageView()

                    if let url = URL(string: result!.data!.pic_url!) {
                        clientImageView.image = UIImage(named: "System/defaultAvatar")
                        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                clientImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                                self?.setNavBarTitle(image: clientImageView.image!)
                            } 


                        }
                        task.resume()
                    } 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

private func setNavBarTitle(image: UIImage) {
    // Crashes here -> Thread 11: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    guard let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height else {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: "WARNING: UIImageView.image must be used from main thread only" shows up for self?.setNavBarTitle(image: clientImageView.image!) line, does this line also need to go inside DispatchQueue.. ?

Comment: yeah sorry, I will just put it there in my answer too. Could you try if it crashes with weak self?

Comment: Tx. It didn't crash so far. I'll keep testing it though.

Comment: I also added setNavBarTitle function to my answer, in your code, you use self.navigationController! - the exclamation mark at the end also might crash the app if the VC does not have a navigationController. I updated it with "?" in my answer, this is safer.

Comment: Sorry it still crashes.

Comment: Did you also make the changes I noted in my last comment?

Comment: Yes I did, it still crashes. I've added a guard around it which prevents it crashing. It prints "navigationBarHeight nil returning" most of the time. Is it the guard solution or we missing something else?        guard let navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height else {
            print("navigationBarHeight nil returning")
            return
        }

Comment: Yeah probably thats the reason because, even though ? will not crash at first when you check navigationController. It will assign nil to navigationBarHeight, then when you try to access it, it will crash anyways. Yeah guard, or if-let is way to go for such case. I will edit my answer.